# How to style WordPress Navigation system to look like this?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm using bootstraps and custom CSS on a custom Wordpress theme and I'm trying to style WP's nav system to look exactly like this hardcoded HTML. I've done this but its not even close.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'menu_class' => "navbar-nav" ) );?>
```

Here is the custom HTML and CSS.

```
<div id="sidenav">

    <div class="navbar-nav flex-column">

        <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a>

            <div id="sidenav-accordion" data-children=".collapse-container">

            <div class="nav-item collapse-container">

            <a href="#" class="nav-link custom-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" aria-controls="grantsDropdown" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#grantsDropdown" data-parent="#sidenav-accordion">Chapter 1</a>

                <div class="collapse custom-dropdown" id="grantsDropdown">

                <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Text<span class="dropdown-number"></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Text<span class="dropdown-number"></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Text<span class="dropdown-number"></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Text<span class="dropdown-number"></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Text<span class="dropdown-number"></span></a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Text<span class="dropdown-number"></span></a>

                </div>

            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Chapter 2<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Chapter 3<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Chapter 4<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Chapter 5<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Chapter 6<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Chapter 7<span class="sr-only"></span></a>

            </div>

            </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Along with bootstraps, here is the custom CSS.

```
nav.side-nav {padding:0;height:100%;position:fixed;max-width:inherit}

nav.side-nav .logo {height:7rem}

nav.side-nav .navbar-nav {width:100%}

nav.side-nav .navbar-nav .nav-link {padding:2rem 1rem;color:#fff;font-weight:700;border-bottom:1px solid #526173;width:100%;}

nav.side-nav .navbar-nav .nav-link.active,nav.side-nav .navbar-nav .nav-link:active,nav.side-nav .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus,nav.side-nav .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover {background-color:#1b2125;transition:all .1s ease-in-out;width:100%;}

nav.side-nav .custom-toggler[aria-expanded=true]{background:#1b2125}

nav.side-nav .custom-dropdown{background:#1b2125;transition:opacity .2s ease-in-out;transform:scale(1)}

nav.side-nav .custom-dropdown.show{display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-ms-flex-flow:column nowrap;flex-flow:column nowrap}

nav.side-nav .custom-dropdown .dropdown-link{display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;padding:.5rem 2rem;color:#fff;font-weight:700;border-bottom:1px solid #526173}

nav.side-nav .custom-dropdown .dropdown-link.active,nav.side-nav .custom-dropdown .dropdown-link:active,nav.side-nav .custom-dropdown .dropdown-link:focus,nav.side-nav .custom-dropdown .dropdown-link:hover{text-decoration:none;background:#95c900}
```

Comment: Hi Bo Lane, could you use the code editor or code-pen to show us the desired output ? `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 'menu_class' => "navbar-nav" ) );?>` : this is your only attempt so far ? What else have you tried ? Have you seen the menu structure using devtools ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom HTML structure for your navigation you have to use a walker.

```
wp_nav_menu([
    'theme_location' => 'primary',
    'walker'         => new NavWalker(),
]);
```

I use for bootstrap navigations this one: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap/wp-bootstrap-navwalker